# cron job time managment

Tags: redhat, cron

I have `cron` job A and B (both jobs run every minute) from 9.00AM to 6.00PM I like to make the second one run after the first one in 30 second.both `cron` job should be run by root user.

for example if the `cron` job A start to run at 9.00.00 AM `cron` job B should start at 9.00.30 AM.

Comment: Why don't you just `sleep 30` as the first step on your second (B) job?

Comment: Note that it is usually a very bad practice to run two cron jobs where one depends on the other, as this creates a race condition. Sooner or later the second job will win the race, even if you give teh first job a 30 second head start...

Comment: I would just integrate the two separate jobs in a single job file to ensure that they always run sequentially one after the other. For instance a trivial: `run-a && sleep 5 && run-b`. - For something completely different: If you run cron-jobs that closely together, you may want to run them less frequently and do a number of loops from within the job with internal job-control. Fot inspiration: http://blog.booking.com/non-daemons-advanced-daemons-that-arent-daemons.html

Comment: @HBruijn thank you, I will try it, this idea is much better than two cron job.